# Can an rfid reader capture strikes from a foam sword with cards attached?

Tags: python, rfid

I am using the PN5180 RFID reader to capture cards that will be attached to a foam sword. The issue I am having is the reader is not quick enough to capture the uid consistently. This is the code that I am using with pyPN5180 library.

```
from PN5180 import PN5180
import sys
import time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_debug = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else ''
    debug = True if check_debug == '-v' else False

    reader = PN5180(debug=debug)
    while True:
        cards = reader.inventory()
        print(f"{len(cards)} card(s) detected: {' - '.join(cards)}")
        time.sleep(.2)
```

If i set time.sleep() to anything lower than .2 the cards fail to read just about every time so I imagine this is a hardware issue. If so, are there any rfid readers that can read fast enough to detect quick strikes with a foam sword. If not, is there anything else that could do this?